# Jira API issue/bulk with expand?

Tags: jira-rest-api

When issues are created in Jira Rest API with issue/bulk the response only gets the id, key and self (url of the issue). As it is a massive creation we need to get the summary also in this response.

We have tried **?expand** parameter but it is not working as I think it is a POST call.

¿Has anybody obtained any different response when creating POST issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, the [bulk issue create endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-bulk-post) does not support the *expand* parameter, so there is nothing to be gained by submitting that parameter in the request.

Also, as per the documentation, that endpoint returns a *CreatedIssue* object, which contains:

- **id.** *string* The ID of the created issue or subtask.
- **key.** *string* The key of the created issue or subtask.
- **self.** *string* The URL of the created issue or subtask.
- **transition.** *NestedResponse* The response code and messages related to any requested transition.

So, there is nowhere in the response to extract the value of the *summary* field from.